# Jquery Tabs - Too many tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I am using JQuery tabs. The problem is when there are too many tabs, some tabs are squeezed to the next line and the layout looks weird. I am not setting the "width" property of the `<div>` of the tab. Is there anyway to have the `<div>` to auto stretch instead of squeezing the tabs to the next line?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After I took a look a the css file and played around with the style a bit, I needed to add "display:inline" to ".ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li"

Also, when the there are too many tabs, some tabs are pushed down to a new line. Some tabs might shift if I click on an item in the first tab. I fixed this by removing "padding-bottom" in ".ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-selected "

Answer (score 4):

If i look at the provided CSS theme, i would play around with :

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li { position: relative; float: left; border-bottom-width: 0 !important; margin: 0 .2em -1px 0; padding: 0; }
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a { float: left; text-decoration: none; padding: .5em 1em; }
```

try something like:

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li {
width:auto;
min-width:auto;
}
```